# jQuery fade parent if child nodes are styled display:none

Tags: jquery

I have `div`s with class "someclass"; each div has child `div`s with class "otherclass".

I need to check if the divs with "otherclass" are `display:none` and then fadeout the parent with "someclass"

How can I do it every time I click on some checkbox on the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(':checkbox').click(function(){

  if( $('.otherclass').css('display')=='none' ){

    $('.otherclass').parent().fadeOut('normal');

  }

}
```

This is assuming .otherclass is a unique identifier.  Also, if you want to to link these elements to the checkbox that is clicked with, say, the same class it's a little more involved.

```
$(':checkbox').click(function(){

  var el = $(this).attr('class'); //Better to use a unique ID here

  if( $('div.' + el).css('display')=='none' ){

    $('div.' + el).parent().fadeOut('normal');

  }

}
```

Comment: +1 - Ain't JQuery grand?  Think about how much Javascript you'd have to write to do this!

Comment: Sorry, not to be rude or anything. But this is just bad jQuery. If it should work, .attr should be .css. And still, why use .css, when jQuery has a selector for it? :-)

Comment: Oh, good call on the attr @Kordonme. I'm fixing it.  As far as bad jQuery, yes, you've done it using a selector.  I'm trying to project into the future and assume he wants to associate these elements to the checkbox. Maybe i'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(":checkbox").click(function() {
    if(!$(".otherclass:visible").length)
        $(".someclass").fadeOut();
});
```